# ng-model value is undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a view that simply takes in an email and password via ng-model then passes it to a login function in the controller via ng-click. I can't seem to get it working correctly and past posts about scope inheritance and $parent don't seem to solve the issue for me.

the ng-model is under an ion-content and a label which is why my assumptions lead to scope inheritance issues. Also the data binding happening in the view {{user.email}} never updates.

here is a plunker where I attempted to re-create my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/JFlO64xi4nG84xqFDYsv?p=info

HTML

```
<body ng-controller='MyCtrl'>

    <ion-content>
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.email">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-model="user.password">
      </label>
      {{user.email}}
      {{user.password}}
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="login(user.email,user.password)">Log in</button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>

  </body>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }
  $scope.login = function(email,password) {
    console.log("email is: ",email); // will log undefined
    console.log("password is",password); // will log undefined
  };
})
```

I have tried $parent.user.email but this also doesn't work. Can someone please help me figure out what is going wrong here?

Comment: My bet is that <ion-content> is creating an isolated scope.

Comment: Not an answer, but why `login(user.email,user.password)` in the first place? You can access `$scope.user` in `login()` anyway ...

Comment: @davidkonrad Honestly I'm not sure I've seen a lot of code examples where that method was and wasn't used. I actually don't know the standard way to do it.

Comment: @ChrisHermut I believe it does as well; however doing `user.email` instead of an `email` should of fixed that problem from what I have read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set `type="email"`, this will cause validation to take place. When a field is invalid, the underlying model will not be updated. Change the `input`s to `type="text"` to see the difference.

See [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D) on `input[email]` for details, too.

Comment: This solution solved my issues. Data binding doesn't occur with email types until the email is valid. Of course i was just typing in random strings to test that never worked! Also my password input was set to type email because of copy and past sloppy ness; I also had to change that. Everyone is now working as expected thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Changes needed.

```
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.email">

<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-model="user.password">
```

When you test it do not forget to enter an email address. Well validation is a whole another issue

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this has been a well known problem -> **https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/555**

**Solution** : Simply upgrade your **ionic** to 1.1.1.

As @stevuu points out, you should / could also set the input `type` to `text` - upon type `email`, the content will be validated and return `undefined` if `user.email` not is a valid email.

When these two changes is made, it works.

forked plnkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/yPiFQkzfNJFDr1gOWFry?p=preview**

---

You could also take advantage of `type="email"` and show an error message if the email is not valid :

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.email">
...
{{ error }}
```

```js
$scope.login = function(email,password) {
  $scope.error = !email ? 'Email is not valid' : '';
  console.log("email is: ",email); 
  console.log("password is",password); 
};
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/pOl88KdOno0keQwePyvH?p=preview**

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML, try to change the type as text and add the field "name" to your inputs, like:

```
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.email">
```

The name must be the same as your object (model) attribute, in your case, the attribute of your object (model) user here is "email".
So the other input should look like this :

```
<input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-model="user.password">
```

Here the attribute of your object (model) user is password, so the name is "password" too.

Hope that help a bit !